# Code only sends name to DB and sends phone number to email field

Tags: php

I updated code per suggestions but now it only sends name to DB and sends phone number to email field. I have copied new code below.

Form:

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post">
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input  type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Age:</label>
        <input  type="text" name="age" />
    </div>
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" />
    </div>
    <div class="field-box">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And the SQL to send the data on processor.php:

```
function sendData() {  
    //Connecting to sql db.
    $connect = mysqli_connect("XXXXXX","XXXXXXXX","XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");

    //setting values from HTML form
    $name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);
    $age   = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['age']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['phone']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['email']);

    //Sending form data to sql db
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (name, age, phone, email) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$phone', '$email')");
}

sendData();
```

Comment: Previous discussions are not contained in this post, so the problem is unclear. Can you describe it and ask a question, please?

Comment: the age and email address aren't showing up in the DB and the phone number is being sent to the email field

Comment: please show var_dump() outputs of your post variables

Comment: I have no clue about php, but shouldn't there be a `</div>` before `<input type="submit">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch out the existing query with this one and it'll work. Cheers.

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (name, age, phone, email) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $age . "', '" . $phone . "', '" . $email . "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another insert type

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users SET name='$name', age='$age',phone='$phone', email='$email')");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to insert into the db with static parameters. I mean something like this

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (name, age, phone, email) VALUES ('name', 'age', 'phone', 'email')");
```

And check if your query works ! But you can otherwise try this one

```
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO users (name, age, phone, email) VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $age . "', '" . $phone . "', '" . $email . "')");
```

I suggest you use Prepared Statements and if possible PDO

Good Luck